# Extract a specific word from a preceding line

Tags: powershell

I want to find a word at a specific location from a preceding line containing a distinct phrase. Let's say this is the text in our file:

```
<data name="variable" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>key phrase</value>
</data>
```

So I know the `key phrase` and I want to extract `variable`.

So far I have come up with something like this

```
$var= Select-String $DirPath -Pattern 'key phrase' -SimpleMatch  -Context 1  |
ForEach-Object { $_.Line.Split(' ')[4] }
```

I hoped that `-Context 1` would just jump back to the preceding line. Though I am still not sure how to extract `variable` from the line above. `Split(' ')` is not working here well because the word is enclosed in quotation marks.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how your XML looks like but definitely don't see a need to treat it as a plain text file.

As an example, this would return `variableFoo` and `variableBar` as both `value` tags have `key phrase` in them.

```bash
$xml = [xml] @'
<test>
  <data name="variableFoo" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>key phrase</value>
  </data>
  <data name="variableBar" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>key phrase</value>
  </data>
</test>
'@

$xml.SelectNodes('test/data/value[text()="key phrase"]') |
    ForEach-Object { $_.ParentNode.name }
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795504/45375) is definitely the best solution to your problem**: the most *robust* way to parse XML is always to use a *dedicated parser*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Context` parameter accepts one to two (in the form of an *array*, i.e. using `,` as the separator) numbers, specifying the number of lines *surrounding* the lines matching the search pattern, alongside the matching lines.
- Targeting these context lines requires accessing the `.Context` property of the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that `Select-String` outputs, which, in turn, has  `.PreContext` and `.PostContext` properties that contain the pre- and post-context lines.

Therefore, if you were to use plain-text processing, you'd have to extract the `name` attribute value (`'variable'`) via `$_.Context.PreContext[0]`, as shown in the following snippet (note that `-split '"'` is used to split the line by `"`, which means that the second (`[1]`) element contains the value of interest):

```
# Sample input lines.
$lines = @'
<data name="variable" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>key phrase</value>
</data>
'@ -split '\r?\n' 

$lines | 
  Select-String -SimpleMatch 'key phrase' -Context 1 |
  ForEach-Object { ($_.Context.PreContext[0] -split '"')[1] }
```

Output:

```
variable
```